# select empName and managerName from same table based on Id

Tags: mysql, sql

From an `employee` table, I need to fetch `empName` and corresponding `managerName` along with the employee who has no manager.
What `SQL query` for the same.

*example:*
employee table

```
id  empName managerId

1   Nishant 
2   Sanchit 1
3   Anurag  2
```

*output should be:*

```
empName managerName

Nishant
Sanchit Nishant
Anurag  Sanchit
```

I tried below query but it's not returning the actual result.

```
select e1.name , e2.name as managerName from employee e1, employee e2 where e1.managerId = e2.id  ;
```

result is

```
empName managerName

Sanchit Nishant
Anurag  Sanchit
```

Comment: Stack Overflow won’t complete your coursework for you.

Comment: @esqew I updated my question and posted why I posted here. The solution I tried is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ppretty similar to what you are doing, just a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT e1.name as empName, 
       e2.name as managerName
FROM      employee e1 
LEFT JOIN employee e2
       ON e1.managerId = e2.id
```